# WebForms not redirecting to idP login page

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

I'm working my way through the Sustainsys documentation for configuring an Asp.Net WebForms app.  But I'm not getting redirected to the idP login page.  What am I missing?

```
 <sustainsys.saml2 entityId="http://localhost/wingtip-toys" 
                   returnUrl="https://localhost/wingtip-toys" 
                   authenticateRequestSigningBehavior="Never" 
                   publicOrigin="https://localhost/wingtip-toys" 
                   validateCertificates="false">
    <identityProviders>
        <add entityId="http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/wingtip-toys" 
             signOnUrl="http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/wingtip-toys" 
             metadataLocation="http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/wingtip-toys/protocol/saml/descriptor"
             loadMetadata="true" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="false">
        </add>
    </identityProviders>
    <compatibility unpackEntitiesDescriptorInIdentityProviderMetadata="true" />
</sustainsys.saml2>
```

The redirection just attempts to stay internal to the application, ~/login.aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the forms auth tag to redirect to `/Saml2/Signin`.